# Spring authentication against tomcat-users.xml

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, container-managed

I've been given a requirement that an application must be configurable to use either LDAP or container-managed authentication. The LDAP requirement has already been fulfilled, but the container-managed, in this case the container is Tomcat, remains a head-scratcher. How do I use the existing Spring Authentication framework to authenticate a users details against tomcat-users.xml?

Many thanks

Angus

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15143716/280244 - I do not know if this helps, because I do not expect that you could bypass the tomcat authentication to use LDAP.  ....  Have you ever thorough about using the LDAP for Tomcat based authentication, then Spring Security PreAuthentication would help you.